# Eeebuntu inexperienced user, forgot my username but I know my password how can I find it without logging in?

Tags: username

I had lost this computer around the house and now that I'm trying to get back onto it I have completely forgotten my login name

Answer (score 0):

Enter to a root shell in recovery mode in the way it's explained here:  https://askubuntu.com/a/24024/16395

When you have the shell, execute the command:

```
cat /etc/passwd
```

your login name should appear near the end:

```
ubu:x:1000:1000:Ubuntu Start,,,:/home/ubu:/bin/bash
rmano:x:1333:1001:Romano Gtti,,,:/home/rmano:/bin/zsh
geoclue:x:117:127::/var/lib/geoclue:/bin/false
```

you see mine here: `ubu` and `rmano`...

Now you can reboot and enter in the system with your user and password.